# What is wrong with this redirect rule?

Tags: regex, redirect, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I'm using the code below to create a redirect rule in my web.config file in the root directory of a site hosted in a Windows server:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="Redirect https" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript">
      <match url=".*cashpreview\\.com\\.br.*" ignoreCase ="true" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

The rule works for the address http://www.cashpreview.com.br/cashpreview/cashbr.htm but not for
http://www.cashpreview.com.br/cashpreview/janelas.htm . If I try to access the first address, the "https" replace the "http", but the same doesn't occurs for the second address. I need to write the domain in the regular expression because I have multiple domains sharing the same web directory and only this has SSL installed for it. Does somebody knows what could be causing this strange behaviour of the rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I've discovered my errors. I was not aware that the parameter url of the match element contains only the part of the url relative to the directory where the web.config file is located. So, the domain never is part of the url. As I have multiple domains sharing the same web directory, I added a new condition checking the {HTTP_HOST} for the only domain for which I've installed SSL. As I have asp files in the site and I used {REQUEST_URI} that include de querystring, I turned off the appendquerystring attribute. My code now is like below:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="Redirect https" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript">
      <match url=".*" ignoreCase ="true"/>
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*cashpreview\.com\.br" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

That case where sometimes the things go right was only for data cached in my browser. Using a proxy, that case didn't worked the way I was doing before too.